# mysql table index is not effecting

Tags: mysql

I have a question about this query and indexing

my query is :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM s1_training where amt > 0 LIMIT 500
```

and i indexed ( amt ) But its not effected if i have this wheres :

```
WHERE amt != 0
WHERE amt > 0 
WHERE amt < 0
```

the result is :

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  s1_training     ALL     amt     NULL    NULL    NULL    64  Using where
```

The only way index will be used is to set

```
WHERE amt = number ( like amt = 2 )
```

and the result will be

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  s1_training     ref     amt     amt     4   const   1
```

thanks in advance for any help

best regards.

Comment: IS the second query exactly like the first except amt=2?

Comment: @mihai yes it is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the number of rows and the cardinality of values.

For example if most values are `>0` then mysql optimizer will decide to to a table scan since is faster.
For the second condition `WHERE amt=2` this will probably return far fewer values so the index is used because is faster.

Comment: so if i have 100k rows it will table scan again ? what if i have 40k rows ?

Comment: @Benjaminfox It depends on the percentage of rows from the total covered by your conditions